# Acoustic Audio Comparing Library

Tags: c#, algorithm, audio-processing, audio-comparison

I need a software or a library which handles with audio comparison, but not using the tag's inside mp3 ,it should compare similarity or confidence between 2 audio Files, or if i cut a piece from an audio file, the software should point where is that file token from the main audio file (i hope i was clear enough).

So how i heard this technology is called *Audio Acoustic Comparing*, and based on some audio sample file, which we can call *fingerprint*. The software should point me if it finds an equivalent of the input sample or fingerprint, somewhere in the file.

Bests.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare 2 audio files, returning a percentage of difference.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306079/how-do-i-compare-2-audio-files-returning-a-percentage-of-difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[libfooid](http://code.google.com/p/libfooid/) is free. It's dual licensed as GPL and as a BSD like license.

Answer (score 1):

check An Industrial-Strength Audio Search Algorithm (PDF) at http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf

Comment: AFAIK shazam is patented, and the patent holder enforces the patent.

Comment: Is this really a solution to the question which parts of the audio files correspond?

Comment: @Sney I think this one can't give you a good similarity measure, but it most likely can tell you which parts of an audio file are similar.